# Javascript taking string with multiple lines from string sent from c# with \n

Tags: javascript, c#, string

I have sent a string read from a text file in c# to Javascript.
In c# the string takes each new line in the text file as `"\n"`.
But when i send the string to javascript, the string is read a multiline paragraph just like it was in the text file.
I need `"\n"` in javascript also. Can anyone help? Thanks.

C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OldFileName = "Original.txt";
        NewFileName = "Changed.txt";
        ViewType = "Inline";

        if (Request.QueryString["oldfile"] != null)
            OldFileName = Request.QueryString["oldfile"];
        if (Request.QueryString["newfile"] != null)
            NewFileName = Request.QueryString["newfile"];
        if (Request.QueryString["viewType"] != null)
            ViewType = Request.QueryString["viewType"];

        fileName = Server.MapPath("~/CompareFiles/" + OldFileName.Replace("\\", "").Replace("/", ""));
        aFile = File.OpenText(fileName);
        a = aFile.ReadToEnd();
        aFile.Close();

        fileName = Server.MapPath("~/CompareFiles/" +            NewFileName.Replace("\\", "").Replace("/", ""));
        aFile = File.OpenText(fileName);
        b = aFile.ReadToEnd();
        aFile.Close();

        aCopy = a.Replace("\r\n","\\n");
        bCopy = b.Replace("\n", "\\n");
```

...and other remaining codes...not necessary

In javascript:

```
<script>
      var strJson = '<%=strStj%>';
      var items = JSON.parse(strJson);
      var aLines = '<%=aCopy%>';
      var bLines = '<%=bCopy%>';
      aLines = aLines.split("\n");
      bLines = bLines.split("\n");
      var aItem = { StartA: "", StartB: "", deletedA: "", insertedB: "" };
      var out = "";
      //  window.onload = ShowOldFile("oldFileTable");

      //   window.onload = ShowNewFile("newFileTable");

      function ShowOldFile(htmlId) {
          var n = 0;
          out = "";
          for (var fdx = 0; fdx < items.Length; fdx++) {
              aItem = items[fdx];

              // write unchanged lines
              while ((n < aItem.StartB) && (n < bLines.Length)) {
                  WriteLine(n, null, bLines[n], htmlId);
                  n++;
              } // while

              // write deleted lines
              for (var m = 0; m < aItem.deletedA; m++) {
                  WriteLine(n, "d", aLines[aItem.StartA + m], htmlId);
                  n++;
              } // for

              // write inserted lines
              while (n < aItem.StartB + aItem.insertedB) {
                  //  WriteLine(n, "i", bLines[n]);
                  WriteLine(n, null, "", htmlId);
                  n++;
              } // while
          } // while

          // write rest of unchanged lines
          while (n < bLines.Length) {
              WriteLine(n, null, bLines[n], htmlId);
              n++;
          } // while
      }</script>
```

if i send "\ \n" a n preceeding with double slash. it works as single slash \n in javascript which is what i want. but again i cannot replace single slash with double slash in c#.
thanks again

[this image shows how it reads the string in javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqAkf.jpg)

Comment: Show the code where you are sending this string.

Comment: that javascript code is where i am sending the string. To variables alines and blines

Comment: Please add code in question not in image.

Comment: @Leopard aLines and bLines is where i am trying to send string of string a and b. the upper snippet is code behind of lower snippet. Still i have added more code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to "escape" the `\n` in javascript.

`var aLines = '<%=a%>'.replace('\n', '\\n');`

EDIT: @Prabesh, could you please give more info as to what it is you are trying to accomplish? seems like it's a compare changes/revisions type of thing and you need to loop thru the files to then read the changes, which themselves can contain tabs, new lines etc... is this correct?

In that case you should update your c# code so instead of looping thru new lines you split your "new lines" based on your custom delimiter and then you won't need to worry about white space characters breaking your loop.

in C#

```
    aCopy = a.Replace("\r\n","[EOL]");
    bCopy = b.Replace("\n", "[EOL]");
```

in JS

```
  aLines = aLines.split("[EOL]");
  bLines = bLines.split("[EOL]");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not helping.

When i use a = a.replace('\r\n', '\\n'); in C#, it works. But then again i have these conditions with \r and \t. i just want to replace \ with \\ in c#. is there a way? thanks

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by that, but you can always `.replace('\t', '\\t')` and `.replace('\r\n', '\\r\\n')`. What's the problem with that?

Comment: yea i could. but i just wanted to replace single slash with double, which i am not being able to do.

Comment: Ya seems you want to escape all special characters, question for you is, how will you be showing this? because you could easily use `encodeURIComponent` and that will take care of escaping special and right before saving back to C# use `decodeURIComponent` which will add back the correct whitespace characters... Edit: ignore question just saw your updated code

Answer (score 0):

javascript needs to escape some of the characters

```
\n
```

is one of these so you have to add a "\" before that

Edit: just saw Eblin answered it already a little better than me :) just follow his guidline